# Alter NSString to get nothing back

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

At two stages of my app's runtime, I am sending an NSString to the following method.

I receive no warnings or errors in the code editor or the debugger, but when I NSLog the output (secondString), I only get given the memory address of the object.

Is there something I am not doing right here?

```
- (NSString*)validateString
{
NSString *firstString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self];
[firstString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableString *secondString = [firstString mutableCopy];
[secondString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange([secondString length], 0)];

secondString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", secondString];
NSLog (@"%@ and %@", firstString, secondString);

return secondString;

[firstString release];
[secondString release];
}
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Ricky.

Comment: Return should be the last thing here! Everything after will not be called!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh that code is wrong on so many levels.

Here's a simpler version:

```
- (NSString*)validateString {
  NSString *firstString = [self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *secondString = [firstString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%%26" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [firstString length])];

  NSLog (@"%@ and %@", firstString, secondString);

  return secondString;
}
```

The construct `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aString]` is a pretty useless statement, especially when you have `copy` available.  You also have a memory leak and a crash in your code (you create a copy of a string [+1 retain count], assign an autoreleased string into the same variable [+0 retain count, original string lost and leaked], and then release the autoreleased string [crash when the autorelease pool drains]).

Answer (score 3):

First some comments:
1) Everything after the return will not be executed, so the last to statements are useless (dead code).
2) If not created with `+alloc`, you can assumed that `NSString` instances are autoreleased, thus you do not need to send the `-release` message to `firstString`.

**Edit**: As Peter Hosey pointed out, you must however release the string obtained by `-mutableCopy`.

To answer your question:
`-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` returns a pointer to the newly created instance, so you have to save it.

```
- (NSString*)validateString
{
NSString *firstString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self];
firstString = [firstString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableString *secondString = [firstString mutableCopy];
[secondString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange([secondString length], 0)];

 secondString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", secondString];
 NSLog (@"%@ and %@", firstString, secondString);

 [secondString release];

 return secondString;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

- You need to use %%26 if you want the string "%26"
- your NSMakeRange is backwards
- your return is too early, and you don't need to release the strings anyway

Comment: And what @swegi said about stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Comment: The questioner does need to release the string obtained from `mutableCopy`.